# how to use updateValue to add an object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a User Struct that I'm casting to Json to be able to get into NSUserDefaults...

```
import Foundation

struct User {
    var name = ""
    var stores: [Store] = []

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        if let name = json["name"] as? String,
            storesJSON = json["stores"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
        {
            self.name = name
            self.stores = storesJSON.map { Store(json: $0)! }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    init() { }

    func toJSON() -> [String: AnyObject] {
        return [
            "name": name,
            "stores": stores.map { $0.toJSON() }
        ]
    }

}
```

and I am using a Data Manager class (Singleton) to add a new User.  But I can't figure out what to pass into updateValue in my addPerson function below? Alternatively is there another way to get this object into NSUserDefaults?

```
import Foundation

class DataManager {

    static let sharedInstance = DataManager()

    var users = [String : User]()

    init() {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let var userFromDefaults = userDefaults.objectForKey("users") as? [String : User] {

            users = userFromDefaults

        }

        else {
            // add default values later

        }


    }

 var userList: [String] {
        var list: [String] = []
        for userName in users.keys {
            list.append(userName)
        }
        list.sort(<)
        return list
    }

 func addPerson(newUserName: String) {
        users.updateValue(User(), forKey: newUserName)
 //       saveData()
    }
```

Comment: In your addPerson, shouldn't you send json object, since you use it to create User in its init method?

Comment: I can't get the right syntax though is my problem

Comment: Will `var users = [String : User]()` it have more the 1 users?

Comment: yes, the (app user) adds names via a table view and I want to create a new User everytime I get a new name (string) from the table view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your interface of the `addPerson` function, use `addPerson(newUser: User)` instead of using `addPerson(newUserName: String)` as @iosDev82 said:

```
// Because your addPerson function needs two parameters: a name and a user object
func addPerson(newUser: User) {
    users.updateValue(newUser, forKey: newUser.name)
 //       saveData()
}
```

so you can:

```
let newName = textField.text.capitalizedString
let newUser = User(["name": newName, "stores" : []])

DataManager.sharedInstance.addPerson(newUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know how to create a `User` object. And that is what you should pass as an argument to your following function. Something like this.

```
var aUser = User(["name": textField.text. capitalizedString])
DataManager.sharedInstance.addPerson(aUser)
    func addPerson(newUser: User) {
           users[newUser.name] = newUser
    // saveData()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you but then how do I get the String I'm passed in my tableView into a User to put into addPerson?                                                                          var newName = textField.text.capitalizedString
            
        
            DataManager.sharedInstance.addPerson(newName)

Comment: but (json: [String: AnyObject])  and you have [String : String]?

Comment: the AnyObject is supposed to be an empty array of store